# error while developing a simple android app

Tags: android

I am trying to create a simple android app. I followed the following link. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html.

In the developers website they asked me to edit activity_main.xml.in which they asked to delete the text view and change the relative layout to linear layout. To my surprise, my activity_main.xml was different from the developer  and i edited it with exactly wat they mentioned in the tutorial. but now when i went through the project folder i found another xml file which is named fragment_main.xml(resembled developers activity_main.xml) and this xml contained tags like relative layout and textview which was not there in my activity_main.xml. I do not know how and why this happend. I am confused whether to edit my fragment_main.xml just the way i did for activity_main.xml?

MainActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new       PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
```

Now i am getting error in my Mainactivity.java.

the error says that the container cannot be resolved or is not a field.

This is how my activity_main.xml looks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="@string/edit_message"/>

<Button  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/button_send"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

this is how my fragment_main.xml looks.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/edit_message" />
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you are not closing your RelativeLayout with `</RelativeLayout>` is that a copy-paste error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this tutorial before for a similar question - the answer is to include this attribute for the LinearLayout in activity_main.xml.

```
android:id="@+id/container"
```

If I remember correctly, your fragment_main.xml is for an activity that extends FragmentActivity which comes later.

Comment: Thank u so much. Adding this in my activity_main.xml worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

The activity_main.xml is the xml (layout) file for the Activity.

The fragment_main.xml is the xml file for the generated Fragment, which is kinda like a small view inside of an activity.

If you're trying to create a simple app, delete the fragment_main.xml, it's not needed for a simple app. Also delete any code in the Activity that is related to Fragments (fragment mangers, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
 if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
}
```

the `R.id.container` cannot be resolved, because there is no element with this id in your layout

You will have to add container id to your layout or just add `0` container id, like this:

```
 if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(0, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
}
```

Strange is that you use Fragments though, since the linked tutorial is not about Fragments...

Comment: tried adding container id to the layout and it worked. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Fragment is a part of an activity, and has its own life-cycle. It's a bit challenging for beginners to understand fragments. 
Accidentally, you may have created a fragment in your application. The default activity in android (Main Activity.java) would look something like this, with only one xml file associated with it(activity_main.xml).

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom= "@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft=   "@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight=   "@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop=     "@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

If possible, try creating another application with default settings.